# does polars support columns selection using boolean type?

Tags: python-polars

I want to select those columns whose all rows value is null. In pandas, I can use:

```
nan_columns = specific_data.columns[specific_data.isna().all()]
```

but I found its logic may be a little hard for polars. I found it:

```
 nan_columns = specific_data[:, specific_data.select(pl.all().is_null().all()).row(0)].columns[0]
```

Am I wrong? Or is there better solution for it?

Answer (score 2):

**Note.** Please take a look at [this](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6895) polars discussion page to better understand the intricacies of data-dependant column selection and implications on lazy/eager evaluation.

Lets consider a dataframe defined as

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3],
    "b": [None, None, None],
    "c": [True, False, True],
})
```

which looks as follows

```py
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ b    ┆ c     │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ f32  ┆ bool  │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ null ┆ true  │
│ 2   ┆ null ┆ false │
│ 3   ┆ null ┆ true  │
└─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

You could now use

```py
df.select(col for col in df if col.is_null().all())
```

or

```py
df.select(col.name for col in df.select(pl.all().is_null().all()) if col.item())
```

The latter will ensure the inner conditions are computed in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Polars does support column selection using boolean masks like Pandas does.

Pandas syntax:

```py
df[mask]
# OR
df.loc[:, mask]
```

Polars syntax:

```
df[:, mask]
```

Full example:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": ["x", "y", "z"],
        "b": [1, 3, 5],
        "c": [2, 4, 6],
    }
)

mask = [True, False, True]

df[:, mask]
```

Output

```
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ x   ┆ 2   │
│ y   ┆ 4   │
│ z   ┆ 6   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

If your boolean mask depends on the DataFrame data, see [Hericks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77670917/2132753).